# How to migrate Mockito 1.x mocking setup in @Before method to Mockito 2.x?

Tags: mockito

I am trying to migrate thousands of tests from Mockito 1.x to Mockito 2.x. Some tests (currently) place the common mocking setup in the @Before method, say:

```
@Before
public void before() {
   //...
   Mockito.when(something.doStuff(Mockito.<Boolean>any())).thenReturn(result);
   //...
}
```

The tests fail with something like:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at ...SomeClassTest.before(SomeClassTest.java:<line-number>)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

I am not sure whether the fact that this is in the @Before method is the cause but it sure looks like it may be but I am hoping for some quick pointers before I start digging elsewhere...

Does anyone know if stuff like this is officially supported in @Before methods or not?

Comment: Mockito doesn't know or care whether you use it in a Before-annotated method or not. If you want help, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Have you read the error message? It already gives some interesting hints.

Comment: OK.. In the same class, some @Test methods do call Mockito.verify, but some do not. I think the original developers didn't do it all that well and they only set up mocking and then call methods hoping they won't explode but assert nothing. Could they be the cause?

Comment: If you want help, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Have you read the error message? It already gives some interesting hints.